# spacial character replacement using sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed

I have a string in a dat file

```
Times-New   $\Gamma$
```

and I want to replace it using sed or awk (I would prefer to use awk) utility  with

```
/Symbol G
```

I could replace only one $ sign but failed for the remaining text.

So what I want is

```
sed   's/Times-New   $\Gamma$/Symbol G/g'  case.dat
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: `sed -E 's/Times-New[[:blank:]]+\$\\Gamma\$/Symbol G/g'  case.dat`

Comment: @anubhava, might have to escape `/` before Symbol like so: `sed -E 's/Times-New[[:blank:]]+\$\\Gamma\$/\/Symbol G/g'`

Comment: Thank you very much. it worked with sed -E 's/Times-New[[:blank:]]+\$\\Gamma\$/\Symbol G/g'  . I removed one "/" near Symbole.

Comment: The part I don't understand is "prefer to use awk". Why? `sed` is perfectly capable of performing this task, with a much smaller footprint than `awk`.

Comment: Sir, I am little bit familiar with awk so I ask about it. Nowadays I am using sed also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples. We need  to escape `\` and `$` to make `awk` treat them as a literal character in program.

```
awk '{gsub(/Times-New   \$\\Gamma\$/,"/Symbol G")} 1' Input_file
```

OR as per OP's comment try(Thanks to anubhava sir for adding solution):

```
awk '{gsub(/Times-New[ \t]+(G|\$\\Gamma\$)/, "/Symbol G")} 1' Input_file
```

---

---

With GNU `sed` try:

```
sed -E 's/Times-New   \$\\Gamma\$/Symbol G/g' Input_file
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, it worked for me. Input_file may have /Times-New   G  instead of Times-New   $\Gamma$  So can we make a awk script  which pick either of the available in Input_file and replace with /Symbol G  ?

Comment: @astha: Use: `awk '{gsub(/Times-New[ \t]+(G|\$\\Gamma\$)/, "/Symbol G")} 1' Input_file`

Comment: Dear Sir, it worked for me. Thank you. I am posting a gnu related question. If you are expert with that, please help me there too.

Comment: Sir, my new question is posted here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62091870/plots-using-gnu-using-two-files    This is a bit complex but as an expert you will get what I need.